# Reading RFID with arduino

Tags: arduino, serial-port, decoding, rfid, arduino-c++

I'm trying read a RFID with a [GP-60a](https://www.promageurope.com/products/rfid-readers-and-writers/gp60-long-range-rfid-reader-gp60a.htm) reader.

I've manged to get something from it but I'm unable to decode the data I'm getting to the expected value.

This is the code I have to read from the reader:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial readerSerial (D3,D4); //rx,tx

char c; 

void setup() {  
    Serial.begin (9600);
    readerSerial.begin (9600);

    Serial.println ("Starting...\n");
}

void loop() {

    if(readerSerial.available())
    {
        while(readerSerial.available ())
        {       
            c = readerSerial.read();

            Serial.print(c,HEX);
            Serial.print (' ');
        }

        Serial.println();
    }

    delay(500);
}
```

I have a RFID with the decimal value of 111 (HEX:6F).

I was expecting the output to be

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 F
```

But what I get is this

```
3F E6 E6 E6 E6 E6 E6 E6 66 66 29 D6 F2 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

I had to change set the SoftwareSerial configuration to SERIAL_8N1

```
SoftwareSerial readerSerial (D3,D4,SERIAL_8N1); //rx,tx
```

and print just the char

```
Serial.print(c);
```

Who knew rubber ducking the internet works?